# Get property dynamically in c

Tags: c, search, select, dynamic, properties

I'm new to C. I'm building a very tiny "database" while I'm learning. I undestand most of the basics in C, but I'm having trouble with Pointers and Arrays.

I would like to create a simple key-value find function. The key is entered by the user as an argument (argv) when the program is executed.

**I'm stuck at printing specific dynamic *columns* of a row**. I would like to do something like this:

```
myArray[i][key] // the key is dynamic, i is from a loop
```

Here is the find function:

```
void Find(char *key, char *value){
    // Print intention to terminal
    printf("\nGet where %s=%s\n", key, value);

    // Get rows
    struct Address *rows = conn->db->rows;

    // List rows
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if(rows[i].set){
            printf("rows[%d] = %s\n", i, rows[i][key] ); // <-- how to do this?
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Address Structure:

```
struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char name[512]; 
    char email[512];
};
```

And here is the Database Structure:

```
struct Database {
    struct Address rows[100];
};
```

Comment: Can we see `struct Address`? It looks like you're trying to use a string as a key to access something (as with a Python dictionary or Ruby hash), which is a high-level function that doesn't exist in C.

Comment: @emblem Of course! I updated the question. By the way `rows[i].name` is working that is why I tried `rows[i][key]`

Comment: What type should `rows[i][key]` be? It needs to be known at compile time

Comment: @Eric mostly strings/character arrays

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Does `key` should match `id` or `name`? What you are trying to print? Print `name`?

Comment: That's not my point. There does not exist a T for which you can write `T result = rows[i][key]`, and guarantee it would compile for any value of key.

Comment: @tivn ideally I would like to be able to select data by all of the methods, id, name, set and email too. My goal here is that I can select data dynamically without having to write a bunch of if-else statements for every method in the for loop.

Comment: @Adam, basically a `struct` field name can not be accessed dynamically. So you will need if-else statement for each field.

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as you can get:

```
// we have to return void*, because we don't know what type to expect
void* getField(struct Address* addr, char* field) {
    if(strcmp(field, "name") == 0) return &addr->name;
    if(strcmp(field, "id") == 0) return &addr->id;
    if(strcmp(field, "email") == 0) return &addr->email;
    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't help as much as you might hope, because:

```
char* key = "name";
void* value = getField(&row, key);
// uh oh - we don't know what type `value` points to. Better double check:

//               This changes per field   V              V  And so does this
if(value == &row.name)  printf("row.%s = %s\n", key, *(char(*)[512])value);
if(value == &row.email) printf("row.%s = %s\n", key, *(char(*)[512])value);
if(value == &row.id)    printf("row.%s = %d\n", key, *(int*)        value);

// We could conceivably write a function to return the correct format specifier, but
// the language does not allow us to write a function to do the appropriate cast
```

Comment: Well this is definetely a solution to the main problem! :P However what I would like to achieve is to select the fields dynamically so I don't need to write those if else statements. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: _"Well this is definetely a solution to the main problem"_ - no it isn't, because you can't do anything with the result

Comment: The `if()` construct is as close as you are going to get.  `switch () {...}` looks very similar once compiled.

Comment: @Eric - yes, but if with the string array (say `char array[max][]={"name",...};`)  there is an accompanying enum, say enum {NAME,.,...,MAX};, then the enum values can be used as `case:` values, and in turn as the index to the array of strings to pull name, id, or email strings.  This is what I started to do in an answer a few minutes ago.  (albeit without the benefit of some of the information you have since put together)

Comment: @Eric, rather than `getField()`, `printField()` would be more useful.

Comment: @tivn: `void strifyField(struct Address* addr, char* field, char* dest, int n)` is probably where you'd need to go with that

Answer (score 0):

***I would like to create a simple key-value find function...***
and
***I'm stuck at printing specific dynamic columns of a row...***

From your written descriptions (as opposed to the code examples), it appears you are looking for a way to do the following:

***1)*** use an array of struct as a *database*
***2)*** consider the members of the struct as fields of a row (or a record)
***3)*** struct array should be searchable using *key-value* approach
***4)*** executable acts on user input value of key.

Regarding the meaning/context of the word *dynamic*, in the comments you have expressed interest in getting the information you want without using if/else, or other branching methods to search.

But you are using a struct.  I agree that a struct is a good choice here because it accommodates multiple data types, (in this case ints and chars) where using a 2D array restricts to only 1 data type.

Because you have expressed interest in using a struct array as the container for a collection of records ( rows of associated values), searching and manipulating the data at some point requires use of branching.

The code illustration below may miss some of the points you have described, but it does include a way to search a *database* (array of struct, which is simulated in the code), and either:

***print out a column of data***, using

```
void PrintSelectedColumnData(int col);
```

or ***retrieve a single tag-value pair*** using

```
void GetSelectedColumnData(int col, int row, char *data);
```

***Code exmaple***: includes two search functions (executable requires argument of 0 - 3)

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    int set;
    char name[512]; 
    char email[512];
}ADDRESS;

// column names       ID  SET NAME   EMAIL
ADDRESS Address[] = {{1,  1, "Joe", "joe@email.com"}, //for illustration purposes
                     {2,  2, "Ann", "ann@email.com"}, //initialize a struct "database
                     {3,  3, "Ben", "ben@email.com"}, //with fillers in code.
                     {4,  4, "Gil", "gil@email.com"}, //(Can later modify to read from a file)
                     {5,  5, "pat", "pat@email.com"},
                     {6,  6, "Gin", "gin@email.com"},
                     {7,  7, "Jen", "Jen@email.com"},
                     {8,  8, "Wil", "wil@email.com"},
                     {9,  9, "Abe", "Abe@email.com"},
                     {10,10, "Del", "del@email.com"}};

enum {
    ID,
    SET,
    NAME,
    EMAIL,
    MAX_COLS
};

//prototypes
void PrintSelectedColumnData(int col);
void GetSelectedColumnData(int col, int row, char *data) ;

int main(int argv, char *argc[])
{
    int col=0;
    int i;
    char data[512] = {0};

    if(argv == 1) 
    {
        printf("no arguments, leaving");
        return 0;
    }
    col = atoi(argc[1]);

    PrintSelectedColumnData(col);

    GetSelectedColumnData(col, 5, data);//Example: get sixth record of column data
                                        //call with changed arguments to retrieve different data
    switch(col) {
        case ID:
            Address[5].id = atoi(data);
            break;
        case SET:
            Address[5].id = atoi(data);
            break;
        case NAME:
            strcpy(Address[5].name,  data);
            break;
        case EMAIL:
            strcpy(Address[5].email,  data);
            break;
        default:
            printf("%d is not valid, must used values 0 - 3\n", col);
            break;
    }

    getchar();//stop execution to view resuls   
    return 0;
}

void PrintSelectedColumnData(int col)
{
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<sizeof(Address)/sizeof(Address[0]);i++)
    {

        switch(col) {
            case ID:
                printf("ID %d: %d\n", i+1, Address[i].id);
                break;
            case SET:
                printf("SET %d: %d\n", i+1, Address[i].set);
                break;
            case NAME:
                printf("NAME %d: %s\n", i+1, Address[i].name);
                break;
            case EMAIL:
                printf("ID %d: %s\n", i+1, Address[i].email);
                break;
            default:
                printf("%d is not valid, must used values 0 - 3\n", col);
                i = sizeof(Address)/sizeof(Address[0]) + 1;
                break;
        }
    }
}

void GetSelectedColumnData(int col, int row, char *data)
{
    switch(col) {
        case ID:
            sprintf(data, "%d", Address[row].id);
            break;
        case SET:
            sprintf(data, "%d", Address[row].set);
            break;
        case NAME:
            strcpy(data, Address[row].name); 
            break;
        case EMAIL:
            strcpy(data, Address[row].email); 
            break;
        default:
            printf("%d is not valid, must used values 0 - 3\n", col);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `myArray`? What is `Address`? Why has `Address` switched from a class name to a variable name?

Comment: You are using object oriented source terms to ask about C source syntax.  In any case, my previous example has been re-written to address OP's question.  Please let me know if you have any more quesions.

Comment: s/Class/struct/. Also, there's a buffer overflow waiting to happen here if you're not using `strncpy`/`snprintf`